# Self-Q&A , Making the Linux monotonic timer using with system signal

Tags: c, linux, timer, signals

In case of using **MONOTONIC_CLOCK**, There's hard to find **MONOTONIC CLOCK** timer.
also, someone who want to use `setitimer() system API` , that's using the `REALTIME_CLOCK` in most system.

So, I have survey the `timer_create()` api and `timer_settime()` api , it's more lower-level control of what timer clock I want to use.

Here's system signal and timer using examples.

in stack overflow has no space for own code repository for me. 
so, I'm writing example code to Self-Answer posting.

Answer (score 1):

It's using the system **MONOTONIC_CLOCK** timer.

This is some examples of using *linux monotonic timer* call and It's callback with system reserved signal.

I'hope ability man *adds another notification with thread* message or **SIGEV_THREAD** examples of code.

> examples:: alarmtest.c

compile on most linux systems.

```
gcc -o alarmtest alarmtest.c -lrt
```

-- sample source code --

```
/*********************************************************************
   Copyright [2015] [KT Ahn, cpplover@daum.net, kts.ahn@gmail.com]

   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
**********************************************************************/

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

void timer_handler (int signum)
{
        static int count = 0;

        unsigned int    clktime;
        struct timespec res;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res);
        clktime = res.tv_sec*1000+res.tv_nsec/1000000;

        printf("%08d:%s]timer expired %d timers\n",clktime,__FUNCTION__, ++count);
}

void timer_handler_0 (int signum)
{
        static int count = 0;
        unsigned int    clktime;
        struct timespec res;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res);
        clktime = res.tv_sec*1000+res.tv_nsec/1000000;

        printf("%08d:%s]timer expired %d timers\n",clktime,__FUNCTION__, ++count);
}

void timer_handler_1 (int signum)
{
        static int count = 0;
        unsigned int    clktime;
        struct timespec res;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res);
        clktime = res.tv_sec*1000+res.tv_nsec/1000000;

        printf("%08d:%s]timer expired %d timers\n",clktime,__FUNCTION__, ++count);
}

void timer_handler_2 (int signum)
{
        static int count = 0;
        unsigned int    clktime;
        struct timespec res;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res);
        clktime = res.tv_sec*1000+res.tv_nsec/1000000;

        printf("%08d:%s]timer expired %d timers\n",clktime,__FUNCTION__, ++count);
}

void timer_handler_3 (int signum)
{
        static int count = 0;
        unsigned int    clktime;
        struct timespec res;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res);
        clktime = res.tv_sec*1000+res.tv_nsec/1000000;

        printf("%08d:%s]timer expired %d timers\n",clktime,__FUNCTION__, ++count);
}

timer_t myTimer(int id, void (*handler), int intms)
{
    struct itimerspec its;
    timer_t timerid;
    struct sigevent sev;
    sigset_t mask;
    struct sigaction sa;
    /* Establish handler for timer signal */

    printf("Establishing handler for signal %d\n", SIGRTMIN+id);

    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIGRTMIN+id, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("sigaction error\n");
        return (timer_t)-1;
    }

    /* Block timer signal temporarily */

    printf("Blocking signal %d\n", SIGRTMIN+id);
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGRTMIN+id);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("sigprocmask error\n");
        return (timer_t)-2;
    }

    /* Create the timer */

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGRTMIN+id;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sev, &timerid) == -1)
    {
        printf("timer_create error\n");
        return (timer_t)-3;
    }

    printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) timerid);

    printf("Unblocking signal %d\n", SIGRTMIN+id);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("sigprocmask error\n");
        return (timer_t)-5;
    }

    /* start the timer */
    its.it_value.tv_sec = intms / 1000;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = (intms%1000) * 1000000;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;

    if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("timer_start error\n");
        return (timer_t)-3;
    }

    return timerid;
}

int main ()
{
        struct sigaction sa, sa1, sa2;
        struct itimerval timer, timer1, timer2;

        /* Install timer_handler as the signal handler for SIGVTALRM. */
        memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
        sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
        sigaction (SIGRTMIN+0, &sa, NULL);

        memset (&sa1, 0, sizeof (sa1));
        sa1.sa_handler = &timer_handler_1;
        sigaction (SIGRTMIN+1, &sa, NULL);
        //sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa1, NULL);

        memset (&sa2, 0, sizeof (sa2));
        sa2.sa_handler = &timer_handler_2;
        sigaction (SIGRTMIN+2, &sa, NULL);
        //sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa2, NULL);

        /* Configure the timer to expire after 250 msec... */
        timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        timer.it_value.tv_usec = 250000;

        /* ... and every 250 msec after that. */
        timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 250000;

        /* Configure the timer to expire after 900 msec... */
        timer1.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        timer1.it_value.tv_usec = 900000;

        /* ... and every 900 msec after that. */
        timer1.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        timer1.it_interval.tv_usec = 900000;

        /* Configure the timer to expire after 1800 msec... */
        timer2.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
        timer2.it_value.tv_usec = 800000;

        /* ... and every 1800 msec after that. */
        timer2.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
        timer2.it_interval.tv_usec = 800000;

        /* Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is executing. */
 //       setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);
  //      setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer1, NULL);
   //     setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer2, NULL);

        myTimer(1, timer_handler_0, 600);
        myTimer(2, timer_handler_1, 900);
        myTimer(3, timer_handler_2, 1200);
        myTimer(4, timer_handler_3, 1500);
        /* Do busy work.  */
        while (1);
}
```

results::

```
kt.ahn@Linux:~/work/test_c_code$ ./alarmtest
Establishing handler for signal 35
Blocking signal 35
timer ID is 0xb8b010
Unblocking signal 35
Establishing handler for signal 36
Blocking signal 36
timer ID is 0xb8b030
Unblocking signal 36
Establishing handler for signal 37
Blocking signal 37
timer ID is 0xb8b050
Unblocking signal 37
Establishing handler for signal 38
Blocking signal 38
timer ID is 0xb8b070
Unblocking signal 38
2060673821:timer_handler_0]timer expired 1 timers
2060674121:timer_handler_1]timer expired 1 timers
2060674421:timer_handler_0]timer expired 2 timers
2060674421:timer_handler_0]timer expired 2 timers
2060674421:timer_handler_2]timer expired 1 timers
2060674721:timer_handler_3]timer expired 1 timers
2060675021:timer_handler_0]timer expired 3 timers
2060675021:timer_handler_0]timer expired 3 timers
2060675021:timer_handler_1]timer expired 2 timers
2060675621:timer_handler_0]timer expired 4 timers
2060675621:timer_handler_2]timer expired 2 timers
2060675921:timer_handler_1]timer expired 3 timers
2060676221:timer_handler_0]timer expired 5 timers
2060676221:timer_handler_3]timer expired 2 timers
2060676821:timer_handler_0]timer expired 6 timers
2060676821:timer_handler_0]timer expired 6 timers
2060676821:timer_handler_2]timer expired 3 timers
2060676821:timer_handler_1]timer expired 4 timers
2060677421:timer_handler_0]timer expired 7 timers
^C
```